# Improve performance of a stand-alone table join in a Feature Service

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server, performance, arcgis-rest-api, feature-service

I have an mxd with data-driven pages using Feature Layers from ArcGIS for Server (Workgroup Standard) with MS SQL Server Express.  The DDP index layer has a join to a stand-alone table.  I am displaying values from the stand-alone table on the layout.  I know the join is the bottleneck as simply moving the text box around on the layout causes a CPU spike (but not to 100% and no other resources max out) on the server.  (I'm looking at it with RD.)   Looking at the logs I can see a bunch of REST requests, as expected.

These are the feature layers:

Polygons for DDP: https://gisserver/arcgis/rest/services/myData_featurelayer/FeatureServer/0

Table: https://gisserver/arcgis/rest/services/myData_featurelayer/FeatureServer/3

(Layers 1 and 2 are not in the mxd.)

The DDP text field:

```
<dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="3.inactive_acres" domainlookup="true"/>
```

The stand-alone table actually has 15 fields, but I removed all but one from the text box.  I then merely clicked on the text box.  There were then 13 REST requests (side-note: why not 15?) that took 13 seconds according the logs, so it looks like it is re-querying almost anytime you do anything.

Any suggestions on how to improve response time or reduce the number of requests?

- I tried both joins types (keep all and keep only matching).
- I tried rebuilding the index on the stand-alone table.
- You can’t use joins when publishing Feature Layers.
- I know direct SDE/SQL Server connections are faster but that’s not an option.
- At no point are any resources maxed out (I know there’s a 1GB limit on Express but this is the only feature service and it only has four layers).
- Server ping is <1ms.
- Nothing crazy in the Activity Monitor in Management Studio.

I’m running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, 64bit, 8GB RAM (ESXi hypervisor).
Desktop is Windows 7 Pro, 64bit, 3Ghz, 12GB RAM, Gb ethernet.

Comment: Are you saying that you are using this DDP enabled MXD in ArcGIS for Desktop and are merely consuming feature services from ArcGIS for Server, or are you trying to publish a DDP enabled MXD to ArcGIS for Server or ...?  Are you doing this through the GUI or if you are using code then can you provide a code snippet to illustrate what you have tried and where you are stuck, please?

Comment: I'm only using the DDP-enabled mxd in Desktop to consume the feature service.  (An attempt at publishing a geoprocessing service to create the mapbook is on my list, though.)

Comment: Using the DDP toolbar in ArcMap, you can go back and forth between pages; everything is working.  I'm just hoping I'm missing something as merely single-clicking on the text box with the single dyn data string shown above results in 13 REST requests back to the server.  And this is in a fresh mxd with only the two layers (polygon and table) and one text box in layout view.

Comment: Make sure your join attributes are indexed on both tables.